# Trying to understand how to import web-assembly package via webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webassembly

I'm on `webpack@4.43.0` and am trying to use this web assembly library https://github.com/vislyhq/stretch As per docs I am importing some classes from it i.e.

```js
import { Allocator, Node } from 'stretch-layout';

class Base {
  public layoutNode;

  public constructor() {
    this.layoutNode = new Node(allocator, {});
  }
}
```

However when I am trying to build it with webpack (not using any loaders and I have `.wasm` in my `resolve.extensions` webpack config) I am getting following error

> WebAssembly module is included in initial chunk. This is not allowed,
> because WebAssembly download and compilation must happen asynchronous.
> Add an async splitpoint (i. e. import()) somewhere between your
> entrypoint and the WebAssembly module:

To my understanding I need to use `import()` for this module, but how do I make these imports available to my class? Application will fail since we need to await that import? If I do something like this I get an error saying that `Allocator` and `Node` are not constructors.

```
let Allocator: any = null;
let Node: any = null;

import('stretch-layout').then(module => {
  Allocator = module.Allocator;
  Node = module.Node;
});
```

Comment: near  the end of this link is relevant to getting functional '.wasm' loader to work in context of a build on libs containing empscriptem type components .    https://gist.github.com/surma/b2705b6cca29357ebea1c9e6e15684cc

Comment: @RobertRowntree I went through all the comments, still unsure what your suggestion is

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to solve this using latest beta of webpack 5, by adding following experimental flags to config

```
  experiments: {
    asyncWebAssembly: true,
    importAsync: true
  }
```

this way you don't have to worry about any async `import()` statements at all

Comment: `importAsync` [was removed](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/pull/3892) from webpack recently, but just `asyncWebAssembly` seems to be enough.

Comment: Oh, actually, it was just updating webpack from `v4.4.1` to `v5.1.3` what fixed the issue for me - specyfing `experiments` in the configuration was not required at all.