# How to load a wasm file from an NPM package into a React app lazily with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webassembly

I am actually using Next.js, but it uses React and webpack under the hood. I would like to convert [this wasm imagemagick demo](https://github.com/dlemstra/magick-wasm/blob/HEAD/demo/demo.ts) to work in React/webpack/Next.js. How do I do that?

The pieces that I've seen so far is I would probably just need to [`fetch` the wasm module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70821634/169992) so I can get the ArrayBuffer. But I don't know how to get the path from the installed node_modules folder. Or alternative to that, perhaps I could use some webpack plugin (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989746/how-to-export-wasm-from-an-npm-package-in-a-way-that-react-js-would-be-able-to-u)) to generate an output.wasm file locally in the public folder, and then fetch that with an XMLHttpRequest. Or finally, perhaps there just is a way to use a webpack loader to just do `await import('@imagemagick/magick-wasm/dist/magick.wasm')` to lazy load it! Something along those lines is what I *think* should be done, but I don't know which path will lead to success.

Any ideas how to load a wasm module through a webpack system or in Next.js, so it works in the browser?

[image]

[image]

- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/next-js-webassembly-77df3537690
- https://github.com/ballercat/wasm-loader
- [Trying to understand how to import web-assembly package via webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816929/trying-to-understand-how-to-import-web-assembly-package-via-webpack)